# OCaml pattern match

Tags: ocaml

in ast.ml, the structure is below:

```
type beantype =
    | Bool
    | Int
    | TLr of fieldsrec
    | TId of ident
and fieldsrec = { fields : field list }
and field =
    | FIe of (ident * beantype)
```

in printer.ml, i use it like below:

```
let rec print_bean fmt = function
    | Bool -> put fmt "%s" "bool"
    | Int -> put fmt "%s" "int"
    | TLr f -> put fmt "%s" "{"; print_fieldsrec fmt f ; put fmt "%s" "}"
    | TId id -> put fmt "%s" id
and print_fieldsrec fmt = function
    | f :: fe -> print_field fmt f; put fmt "%s" "," ; print_fieldsrec fmt fe
and print_field fmt = function
    | FIe (id, beantype) -> put fmt "%s" id; put fmt "%s" ":"; print_bean fmt beantype
```

However it said the different pattern match in print_fieldsrec

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a list
   but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
     Bean_ast.fieldsrec
```

how can i change the printer.ml?

Comment: `TLr` holds a `fieldsrec`, not a list. Maybe change the pattern to `| TLr { fields=f }`.

Comment: I have try ,you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused by the type `fieldsrec = { fields : field list }`. You should have followed Jeffrey's advice of using `| Fields of field list` instead.

`fieldsrec` is not a list, it is a record containing a list, so

```
print_fieldsrec fmt = function f :: fe -> ...
```

doesn't have the type its name suggests.

Also you forgot the base case for the recursive `print_fieldsrec`.